# How do I parse XML with PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to parse out the XML below with the PHP code shown here but I end up getting a blank screen when it runs.  I've been looking around on stackoverflow for similar questions and other similar responses but I still can't get it to work.

```
    <?php
    $url = 'xml-file.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    // get first book title
    $title=$xml->entry[0]->name;
    // show title
    echo $title;
    echo '<br/>';
    // get second book title
    $title=$xml->entry[1]->name;
    // show title
    echo $title;
    echo '<br/>';
    ?>
```

Here is the XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <feed gd:kind="shopping#products" gd:etag="&quot;lm_25heFT8yiumci9EH1kItJBpg/bXZf0ylJ3aJceGcE1I8C1fJbzgo&quot;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/" xmlns:s="http://www.google.com/shopping/api/schemas/2010">
     <id>tag:google.com,2010:shopping/products</id>
     <updated>2012-01-27T13:41:20.177Z</updated>
     <title>Shopping Products</title>
     <generator version="v1" uri="https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/">Search API for Shopping</generator>
     <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/"/>
     <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?alt=atom"/>
     <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?country=US&amp;q=digital+camera&amp;alt=atom&amp;startIndex=1&amp;maxResults=25"/>
     <link rel="next" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?country=US&amp;q=digital+camera&amp;alt=atom&amp;startIndex=26&amp;maxResults=25"/>
     <link rel="previous" type="application/atom+xml"/>
     <openSearch:totalResults>6446790</openSearch:totalResults>
     <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
     <openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>


    <entry gd:kind="shopping#product">>
      <id>tag:google.com,2010:shopping/products/2860562/9400569674928563633</id>
      <author>
       <name>Amazon.com</name>
      </author>
      <published>2010-08-19T05:50:21.000Z</published>
      <updated>2012-01-26T23:54:26.000Z</updated>
      <title>Canon powershot s95 10 mp digital camera with 3.8x wide angle optical image         stabilized zoom and 3.0-inch lcd</title>
      <content type="text">desc</content>
      <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003ZSHNGS" rel="nofollow noreferrer"/>
      <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products/2860562/gid/9400569674928563633?alt=atom"/>
      <s:product>
       <s:googleId>9400569674928563633</s:googleId>
       <s:author>
        <s:name>Amazon.com</s:name>
        <s:accountId>2860562</s:accountId>
       </s:author>
       <s:creationTime>2010-08-19T05:50:21.000Z</s:creationTime>
       <s:modificationTime>2012-01-26T23:54:26.000Z</s:modificationTime>
       <s:country>US</s:country>
       <s:language>en</s:language>
       <s:title>Canon powershot s95 10 mp digital camera with 3.8x wide angle optical image stabilized zoom and 3.0-inch lcd</s:title>
       <s:description>desc</s:description>
       <s:link>http://www.amazon.com/Canon-PowerShot-S95-Stabilized-3-0-Inch/dp/B003ZSHNGS</s:link>
       <s:brand>Canon</s:brand>
       <s:condition>new</s:condition>
       <s:gtin>00013803126556</s:gtin>
       <s:gtins>
        <s:gtin>00013803126556</s:gtin>
       </s:gtins>
       <s:inventories>
        <s:inventory channel="online" availability="inStock">
         <s:price shipping="0.0" currency="USD">340.41</s:price>
        </s:inventory>
       </s:inventories>
       <s:images>
        <s:image link="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/519z3AjKzHL._SL500_AA300_.jpg"/>
       </s:images>
      </s:product>
     </entry>

     <entry gd:kind="shopping#product">
       <id>tag:google.com,2010:shopping/products/2860562/12997829348635087420</id>
       <author>
        <name>Amazon.com</name>
       </author>
       <published>2010-09-14T13:18:12.000Z</published>
       <updated>2012-01-26T23:07:30.000Z</updated>
       <title>Canon g12 10 mp digital camera with 5x optical image stabilized zoom and 2.8 inch vari-angle lcd</title>
       <content type="text">desc</content>
       <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0041RSPRS" rel="nofollow noreferrer"/>
       <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products/2860562/gid/12997829348635087420?alt=atom"/>
       <s:product>
        <s:googleId>12997829348635087420</s:googleId>
        <s:author>
         <s:name>Amazon.com</s:name>
         <s:accountId>2860562</s:accountId>
        </s:author>
        <s:creationTime>2010-09-14T13:18:12.000Z</s:creationTime>
        <s:modificationTime>2012-01-26T23:07:30.000Z</s:modificationTime>
        <s:country>US</s:country>
        <s:language>en</s:language>
        <s:title>Canon g12 10 mp digital camera with 5x optical image stabilized zoom and 2.8 inch vari-angle lcd</s:title>
        <s:description>desc</s:description>
        <s:link>http://www.amazon.com/Canon-G12-Digital-Stabilized-Vari-         Angle/dp/B0041RSPRS</s:link>
        <s:brand>Canon</s:brand>
        <s:condition>new</s:condition>
        <s:gtin>00013803126815</s:gtin>
        <s:gtins>
         <s:gtin>00013803126815</s:gtin>
        </s:gtins>
        <s:inventories>
         <s:inventory channel="online" availability="inStock">
          <s:price shipping="0.0" currency="USD">395.95</s:price>
         </s:inventory>
        </s:inventories>
        <s:images>
         <s:image link="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/516mn5voF0L._SL500_AA300_.jpg"/>
        </s:images>
       </s:product>
      </entry>


     </feed>
```

Comment: Have you checked your error log for any clues?

Comment: I commend you for not mentioning regexen once in your question.

Comment: What does "still cant get it to work mean" - do you get an error message? What output do you expect? What output do you get?

Comment: Maybe PHP DOM would be a better option, it's a bit more sophisticated than simplexml.

Comment: @symcbean when I open the file, it's just a blank screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see `name` in the XML at this location

```
$title = $xml->entry[1]->name;
```

I do see name at the author:

```
$title = $xml->entry[1]->author->name;
```

And I do see a title

```
$title = $xml->entry[1]->title;
```

Thats probably what you are looking for. Otherwise, do below, for debugging purposes to see how to access everything.

```
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($xml->entry[1]);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score -1):

I always use a seperate DOM parser when working with php and maybe you should too. xml2array is one of them.